# Mysqli prepared statement select query with COLLATE utf8_bin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, collate

I want to make a difference between big and small letters when checking if the key is correct. I have this query:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table WHERE id=? AND key=? 
COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
$stmt->bind_param("is", $id, $key);
$id = $_POST[id];
$key = $_POST["key"];
$stmt->execute();
```

With this, I get a message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

So what's wrong with my query?!

Comment: Why are you trying to use the deprecated `utf8` charset?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that mysqli can't deal with COLLATE properly. 'prepare' returns FALSE and you get the error.
To be able to execute the statement you can use 'query' instead of 'prepare'